Syncing Google Slides and Powerpoint Slides w/ Embedded Videos
I'm looking for a way to sync Google Slides and Powerpoint Slides that are stored in Google Drive and Box respectively. If a video is embedded in a slide in one system, when it's synched to the other system it only shows up as a still frame image of the beginning of the video without a video player.
I've tried a few providers like Insync and GoodSync and everything works great aside from the synching of embedded videos. Ideally embedded videos would be playable in both slide decks after synching without any additional manipulation.
